# Breaking a React-Native application into plugable modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I am looking to write a React-Native application. I want to be able to download new modules at run-time on the device to extend functionality. There would be some core logic that knows how to request new modules based on some form input like a dbs. I do not want to bundle everything into a single monolithic bundle which is what I believe happens now with the built in packager.

This would something similar to how RequireJS works in browser. What I need to know is:

1. How do I build independent modules? react-native bundle doesn't seem to allow me to select which root modules to begin with and only works on root project
2. How can I at run-time request new functionality be injected into the current JavaScript environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get something pretty close to this in JS only. First I had to expose a few more options in the current react-native bundler, mainly, the url (to change the "main" module) and blacklist (to keep from bundling react-native in second bundle) options to their packager (http://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/packager/README.md).

I then had to write a custom fetcher that would download the second bundle and use `eval()` to evaluate it in the current environment.

The one rub is that I had to add `__d('react-native',[],require('react-native'))` in the first bundle which I think work like `define()` from require.js. This exports 'react-native' as an unmangled name that the modules which I plug in can access via normal require() statements. It's a bit confusing at first but from what I can tell they React-native packager works a little like r.js (see http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html).

Answer (score 2):

React native starts by pointing at a JS bundle.  This means that you would at least have to restart the app to reload the js bundle (assuming that you're reading it from a server and not from the ios device itself).

If you did have a way to update the js files on the server (through some sort of web service that updated based on things the user does) then restarting the app could theoretically reload the JS and provide new functionality to the app.

Comment: This is how the current implementation of React-Native works. I wouldn't actually even need to update the jsbundle as they already provide this mechanism via their packager that runs when you start their example app.  Just save my updated node module, and the packager will repackage and being service the new bundle to the app. What I was looking for was the ability start something like a bootstrapper that could then request a second bundle to augment the currently running react-native program.

Comment: As far as i know, that is unplanned and would be pretty hard to do....I'm not an iOS guru though.